# How to compress PNG file in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, png

May I know how to compress a PNG image in Swift?

I know `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is recommended in most replies, but is that only for JPEG? Is there any similar method like `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` which has a parameter to tell the compression quality for PNG images?

I'm new to iOS. Can you please suggest how to handle this kind of PNG compression stuff?

If we need to convert PNG to JPEG first then please let me know how to convert it.

Comment: You can't. If you need to compress your data just use jpeg. Why would you need a compressed PNG?

Comment: @Leo Dabus PNG is compressed. It's just compressed using a lossless algorithm rather than a lossy one. This does make the concept of a "compression quality" setting meaningless, of course, since lossless compression means that the compression quality is always 100% by definition.

Comment: we have some functions which will take photos and save them as PNG images, then upload them to our server, but as huge size of the PNG image, it will take 5-10 mins for uploading.

Comment: If they are **photos** taken with the device's camera, I strongly recommend using JPEG at the highest quality loss (compression ratio) that you can afford, not **PNG**. Haven't checked recently, but shouldn't photos be already saved as JPEG to the library?

Comment: @York That's the downside of using a lossless format. If you want upload faster, either reduce the resolution of the PNG or use a lossy format like JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for all your answers.
finally we pick UIImageJPEGRepresentation.
as the PNG image can be transferred into image data, then we just convert this ImageData with UIImageJPEGRepresentation and set it a lower quality.
to be honest I'm not sure if it is really getting the correct result,
please correct me if this is a terrible mistake.